# Alfresco not allowing more than 1000 active sessions

Tags: java, alfresco

We have installed `alfresco 4.2.e community` edition. While doing load test. It is not allowing more than 1000 active `users/sessions`. Each new login after 1000, gets a token, but if we try to authenticate/proceed further it returns `402 unauthorized`. Even we tried setting `server.maxusers` to **-1** and later to **100000** in ***alfresco.properties*** file but the same happens. ***Single User Mode*** is disabled. We are running it under **tomcat 7** on **java 7** in windows machine. This is an upgraded system from `4.0.e` to `4.2.e`.

Comment: I guess its not working correctly in community edition .. 
[Check](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ACE-3216) Only idea, maybe you can change it on the side of the dabase, somehow [tuneup pools and connection](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/db-config-properties.html)

Comment: Even I was doubting the same but I tried setting max users to 2 and tried logging in. It denied 3rd login completely. As well as I think that the bug is reported with version 5+. or did I understood it wrong?

Comment: If it was reported in v5, there is a big chance it was already in v4, but its just guessing.. If it works with 2 then it seems working. Maybe the have some max number or something and then just ignore it and use some default or something.

Comment: Yeah may be. But some valid reason may pave way for some hacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not related to the max number of sessions rather than to the max number of login tickets which are managed in memory cache:

```
cache.ticketsCache.maxItems=1000
```

Also take a look to the other ticket properties to control ticket livetime

Comment: [I referred this](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/V4.2e/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/repository.properties) for v4.2.e [as well as this](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/repository.properties) for the properties supported by alfresco, but no such property has been mentioned there. May I know where can I refer for all the possible properties supported by alfresco? we've already set ticket validity,single ticket by referring the same but couldn't find this one.

Comment: we tried by putting the property under `tomcat/shared/alfresco-global.properties`. It worked. So apart from properties mentioned in `repository.properties` what are the possible properties can I put in `global.properties`?

Comment: Since alfresco puts the default config files into jars it's not so easy to find them. Take a look into webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-*.jar::alfresco/caches.properties but there is no official documentation I know of which explains the details.

Comment: The OOTBee Support Tools addon provides a view (https://github.com/OrderOfTheBee/ootbee-support-tools/wiki/System%20Information) which shows all the properties set in alfresco-global.properties including those inherited from files inside the Alfresco JARs, and any that may be loaded from JNDI (rarely used, but technically possible).